# How to divide the value in grid view by 1000000(one million) and put a unit after it

Tags: asp.net

I am retrieving data from SQL Server to a grid view in ASP.Net. Below is the grid view after I retrieved the data from the database.

```
Time   | City_1    | City_2   | City_3
02/12  | 30000000  |12000000  |55000000000
02/12  | 14000000  |1000000   |7200000000
```

So I want the values in the grid view to be divided by 1000000(one million) and put "mil" after it. After dividing it, I also want to put a comma in every thousandth place of the remainder value for the ease of the user.
So my grid view will look like this after formatting.

```
Time   | City_1 | City_2  | City_3
02/12  | 30mil  | 12mil   | 55,000mil
02/12  | 14mil  | 1mil    | 7,200mil
```

What I have tried:

Below is the code how I am retrieving the data from SQL Server to the grid view.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("My Connection");

string s = "My Stored Procedure";

con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(s, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

gridView1.DataSource = ds;
gridView1.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Comment: Please include your current gridview markup

Comment: @JonP What do you mean by gridview markup? It's a simple grid view which is displaying the same table as it is in SQL Server

Comment: Are you using bound fields? Template fields? Auto generated columns? A combination of those? If you show how you are declaring your gridview we will have that information. The answer could be different for each of those scenarios. Are the number of columns fixed or can that change over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RowDataBound event. Then loop all the values in the GridView. Then check if the value is a million and then format it using a [custom specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#SpecifierTh).

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow and not the first row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //loop all the cell, but skip the first Time field
        for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            //convert the cell value to a long
            long cellValue = Convert.ToInt64(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);

            //format the value if it is a million or greater
            if (cellValue >= 1000000)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = cellValue.ToString("#,##0,,mil", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}
```